# Составные названия

Tags: прописная-строчная, ономастика

Вот если, скажем, название состоит из двух слов, например, Аю-Даг, оба слова пишутся с большой буквы или только первое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В составных названиях с прописной буквы пишутся все слова, кроме служебных слов и родовых наименований (слов гора, город, залив, море, озеро, остров, река, улица и т.д.). Например, город Нижний Новгород, но Чистые пруды (улица в Москве, на которой имеются пруды). Полный ответ вы получите на сайте http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/24.htm#з_01, §17. Географические и административно-территориальные названия

Comment: К сожалению, топонимы далеко не всегда подчиняются правилам. 
Это правило безусловно справедливо в отношении раздельных написаний. Что касается дефисного и тем более слитного написания - тут, понятно, все по=другому.

Answer (score 0):

В отношении конкретно Аюдага, то сейчас закреплено именно такое, слитное написание (см. словарь имен собственных Ф. Л. Агеенко; правда мало кто такого варианта придерживается). При ранее использовавшемся написании через дефис обе части начинались с заглавной. Но при этом: Медведь-гора, Сапун-гора и проч. Для этих топонималв сейчас тоже возможно слитное написание.

Общего правила нет. Надо смотреть в словари. Но обычно при дефисном написании обе части шли с заглавной, если название предсьавляет собой иноязычный топоним. Русские топонимы, содержащее родовое слово чаще писались с одной заглавной в первой части.

Comment: Я правильно поняла, можно писать "Медведьгора"? На каком основании?

Comment: Нельзя. Правильно Медведь-гора http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%EC%E5%E4%E2%E5%E4%FC%E3%EE%F0%E0

Comment: >Я правильно поняла, можно писать "Медведьгора"? На каком основании?

У Агеенко предлагается "Сапунгора". "Медведьгора" там отсутствует, но де-факто иногда встречается в текстах, наряду с дефисным написанием. 

>Нельзя. Правильно Медведь-гора  
  
Не думаю, что *орфографический* словарь - источник топонимической истины. И потом, оттуда следует только то, что возможно дефисное написание, но не то, что слитное нефозможно.

Comment: Ларf, я задал этот вопрос на Грамоте, но, боюсь, они меня опять проигнорят.

Comment: (Почему меня это не удивляет?)

Comment: Марин, не надо, не дразнитесь...)))

Comment: >(Почему меня это не удивляет?)

(Это мне вопрос?) 
[или Грамоте?]
{А почему бы вам не последовать их примеру?}

>Марин, не надо, не дразнитесь...)))   

<А вы не провоцируйте>.

Comment: Хорошо бы тем, кто составляет карты, ориентироваться на словарь, а не наоборот.